# Why xcframework is not working, whereas framework is working

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, xcframework

I have created a framework. which is using pod tabman inside. When I integrated the framework in Demo application it is working good. But when I create XCFramework[so both device and simulator could be addressed] and integrate XCFramework into Demo app it is giving 2 errors.

1- Failed to build module 'Framework_' for importation due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug

2- No such module 'Tabman' in DerivedData/Debug-iphoneos/Framework_.framework/Modules/Framework_.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.private.swiftinterface

I am attaching snapshot of Demo Application in which I integrated XCFramework.
Please help.

[image]
[image]

Here is the script used to create XCFramework.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by prefixing every import tabman with @_implementationOnly in framework swift files.

So my new line is

@_implementationOnly import Tabman